# Firemonkey, visual themes and AMD crossfire compatibility

Tags: delphi, themes, windows-7-x64, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

After converting a VCL app of mine to FMX (XE3, Windows only) I have gotten a fair amount of bug reports concerning a crash happening shortly after the application has launched, as soon as there is any user interaction as far as I can tell. [Here's a link to a sample bug report, all of them look the same.](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4zTPVtvV)

It seems to be only appearing on Win7 x64, also all of the people who have gotten back to me so far could confirm that they have AMD CrossfireX technology to switch between multiple graphics cards.

The issue can be fixed by either disabling crossfire for my application or by disabling "visual themes" (right click exe, properties, compatibility).

Does anybody have an explanation as to why this could be happening? I was thinking about having visual themes disabled by default, is this possible (e.g. via manifest) or even a good way to tackle that?

Comment: You can disable visual themes by using a manifest that does not mandate comctl32 v6. It would be better to isolate the issue. Does the same happen for a vanilla fmx app. If not, what's special about your app. Will it help to use the latest fmx. Are there qc reports that mention similar issues.

Comment: A vanilla app is running without issues. I have no idea about which characteristics of the app might be related to the problem unfortunately ...

Comment: Then you need to do find out. Unless somebody magically knows the answer.

Comment: Not sure whether you'll still read this, but I rolled an update with a manifest that does not mandate comctl32 v6, and while this seems to have somewhat made the issues less widespread I'm still having users with the same issue. I've used GetDllVersion to make sure the app really uses v5 (it's $50052), the app still crashes but manually disabling visually themes does help.

Comment: That degrades the app in other ways though, doesn't it.

Comment: Sorry, hit the enter button before I actually got to the point of the comment T.T

Comment: So I guess the point is, that whatever disabling visual themes via context menu does, using comctl32 v5 does not do it, and I'm wondering whether there is another way to do so.